# Storing the login time in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to store login time in a mysql database.
What I want is..that when a user logs in..the script should store the current time in the table "user" having a column "last_seen".
last_seen is of DATETIME datatype.

Here's the code I've written(it's a little part of a login script..it works after the user has enter the username and password, and they are matched in the database. :-

```
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
$_SESSION['logged']=1;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = "INSERT INTO user
          (last_seen)
          VALUES
          ('" . $date . "')
          WHERE user_name = '" . $username . "'";
         mysql_query($query, $db) or die (mysql_error($db));
header('Refresh: 5; URL = main.php');
echo "Login successful, redirecting...";
die();
```

This throws me the error :- 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user_name = 'test'' at line 5
(The username of the account from which I'm logging in is :- test)

What do I change so the code works ?The code would store the login time of the user in the db(which would be later accessed at a backend page).

Comment: The error you're getting implies that you have mismatched quotes

Comment: Are you supposed to be updating a column? Or inserting a new row?

Comment: I'm supposed to update the column "last_seen" for the user "$username".

Comment: You should probably start using mysqli

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do the date generation in PHP. It's much easier to just have

```
UPDATE .... SET last_seen=now() WHERE ...
                          ^^^^^
```

in mysql.

Beyond that, an `INSERT` in no way shape or form accepts a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: It's perfect :) You must update Last seen column for the user detail exist in your table :) +1 @Marc B

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = "UPDATE user
      SET last_seen = '" . $date . "'
      WHERE user_name = '" . $username . "'";
```

However, you should use `NOW()` so that MySQL will determine when the user logged in. Also, consider starting a transaction for the time when the password is compared against and when you update the user as logged in, for accuracy's sake.