# How do I log each users time session on a website where my users are stored in an SQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic website made with html/css/php. There is a login page that requires a username and password to access all other areas of the website. The users are stored in a MySQL Database (fields: username, password, store, etc).

I need/want to be able to view **when** the user logged in and how **long** that particular user was logged in for. I need a simplified way to show this data to someone who would not have access to the cpanel.

Sorry for such a vague question, feel free to abuse me and ask for more info and I will reply with what's needed and asked of.

EDIT: Sorry I would like to re-phrase what I've asked for as I think having every individual login sessions would make this log quite too much. What I need more accurately would be:

- How many times they logged in for the month
- Average duration of logins for the month

Example:

- User A has logged in the website 200 times this month
- User A session duration each visit on average 5 minutes

Sorry for the confusion. The examples above would be the data needed.

Comment: I believe this would be your best bet, Seems to have been answered already. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975954/storing-the-login-time-in-a-mysql-database?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You can save timestamp when a user login and logout.

```
$logintime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$logout_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Keep these data in a log table. The difference between this timestamp give the duration.And each tim a person login the value of a feild 'no_of_times' (type:integer,default:0) can be increase +1.